# How to loop ui and li in selenium in a go to select all the profiles displayed in the dropdown (dropdown will be dynamic)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying select all the profiles displayed in dropdown which is in the `ul` and `li` ,here the conflict I am  facing is every time I select the profile then the dropdown disappears again I need to click on the dropdown button and select the profile ,how do I select all the profiles in a go ( how to loop that )?

here is the `html` of the above query

```
<ul id="binduserinul" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
   <li onclick="bindfrofilesmaster('tumblr','kishore3663','kishore3663')">
   </li>
   <li onclick="bindfrofilesmaster('facebook','Kishore Nk','100002876995628')">
   </li>
   <li onclick="bindfrofilesmaster('tumblr','kishor3663','kishor3663')">
    </li>
   <li onclick="bindfrofilesmaster('twitter','KishuNk25','2606831526')">
     </li>
   <li onclick="bindfrofilesmaster('facebook_page','Ask Help ? We do it','1565847693677378')">
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add your code of what you've done.What language Java/C# and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign (search element one more time) inside of the loop

So you need inside of the loop wait for element will be ready (or wait for ajax), reassign element, and to do your action needed.